# Client projectile ignores camera Y-axis in multiplayer shooter

Tags: unity, multiplayer, first-person-shooter

I'm able to spawn the bullet and make it move. But the problem is, only the host can shoot the bullet in the way the camera is facing(takes both X-axis and Y-axis correctly). The client takes only the X-axis of the camera and keeps the Y-axis at zero.

Here's the code for spawning and applying velocity:

```
[Command]
void CmdFire()
{
    GameObject fb = Instantiate(fireBall, spawnPoint.position, spawnPoint.rotation);
    fb.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Camera>().transform.forward * fireSpeed;
    NetworkServer.Spawn(fb);
}
```

And the code for the camera attached to the player:

```
void Update()
{

    mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
    mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

    //Horizontal Looking
    playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);

    //Vertical Looking
    xRotation = xRotation - mouseY;
    xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);
    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);




}
```

Comment: According to [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/networkserver-spawn-not-syncing-rigid-bodys-velocity-on-the-client-side.480056/), UNet only syncs the position when spawning, but not the rigibody velocity. There's some suggested approaches to help in that thread. (Note UNet is being deprecated by Unity. There's also Photon PUN2.)

Comment: Yep. It doesn't pass component's values through the network. This thread solution seems to work fine for now. Thanks.